# Wine hijacked 'text/plain' file's icon

Tags: wine, icons

I recently installed TADS 3 Workbench using Wine and accidentally chose the option to create file type association. Now, all my plain text files have a rather garish icon replacing their default ones.

[image]

What I have tried:

1. Uninstalled TADS
2. Removing mimeinfo.cache (rm ~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache) as well as any .desktop files there created by wine
3. Added

   `<generic-icon name="text-x-generic"/>`

   `<icon name="text-x-generic"/>`

to `/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml` under `<mime-type type="text/plain">`

4. Deleted rm ~/.local/share/mime directory.
5. Removes entire wine prefix.

However, the icons are still the same. Any idea how to mend this?

Comment: Have you tried restarting? Just curious.

Comment: Yes, I did restarted. Didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wine store it's icons in `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor`. And becuase Wine hates you, it stores all the filetype icons not in `mimetypes` directory but in `app` directory of every resolution. In my case this file was named `text-plain.png` but that will depend on it's mimetype. Once you delete those files and reboot the computer, the icons should return to usual (Of course, we have simply removed the image files; somewhere, there is still an entry of that image to be used as the icon)

Another hit-and-miss solution is to change the icon theme.